# Error Login timeout expired

Tags: php, mysql, sql, centos, odbc

Tengo una BD en SQL Server, que estoy conectando con CentOs7, aparentemente he realizado todas las configuraciones correctamente para que funcione en mi sitio web, porque al ejecutar `tsql` desde la consola, me devuelven todas las instancias de las tablas contenidas en la BD

El codigo que uso para la conexion es el siguiente:

```
<?php

// Configuration Settings for connection to Database
$host = '200.72.245.189';
$user = 'sa';
$pass = 'StockN123';
$db   = 'DBMAIN';
$conn = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=$host;PORT=8888;DATABASE=$db";

// Open connection
$db_connect = odbc_connect($conn, $user, $pass);
?>
```

Hize un formulario donde se puede consultar el precio y la lista de todos los productos que estan disponibles en mi sitio web.

Pero al utilizarlo me devuelve el siguiente error:

> Error [unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired

Comment: Espero que esas no sean la IP y credenciales de **producción** de tu BD

Comment: @aeportugal no hay que preocuparse, he cambiado los datos, nada de lo que esta ahí es cierto, todo es a manera de ilustración.